# How to extract the hashtags from twitter page explore?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to extract the tag names (hashtags) from the explore page in twitter using selenium on python3. But there are no special tags or classes or even ids to be able to locate them and save them.

Is there a way that I can extract them even if they change without having to edit my code every time?

I think the following code will take me to the explore page using the link text. But I can not use the same method to locate the tags as they change every now and then.

```py
explore = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Explore")
```

I want to be able to locate the tags and save them into a list so I can use that list in my work later on.

This is the html code for on of the tags:

```html
<span class="r-18u37iz"><span dir="ltr" class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">#ARSBUR</span></span>
```

The classes are not unique and they are used in other elements of the page, so I can not use them.

If there is a way to locate the (#) mark so I can only get the text that includes them.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the **hashtags** from the explore page in twitter i.e `https://twitter.com/explorer?lang=en` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) on *Python 3* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://twitter.com/explorer?lang=en")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/hashtag']>span.trend-name")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://twitter.com/explorer?lang=en")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@href, '/hashtag')]/span[contains(@class, 'trend-name')]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['#MCITOT', '#WorldSupportsKashmir', '#MCIvsTOT', '#11YearsOFViratism', '#ManCity']
  ```

Comment: I tried the xpath way to try and locate the tags, but I had an error.
```python
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```
Just so you know, I changed the link to be (explore) instead of (explorer)

Answer (score 0):

You could dump page source into beautifulsoup 4.7.1 + and use :contains along with class. Your classes appear different from the ones I see but I am making an assumption about url.

N.B. On the page there can be other # under a different class which would make selector `".trend-name, .twitter-hashtag"` .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

d = webdriver.Chrome(r'path\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://twitter.com/explorer?lang=en')
WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".trend-name")))
soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml') 
hashtag_trends = [i.text for i in soup.select('.trend-name:contains("#")')]
print(hashtag_trends)
```

Or test whether .text begins with # for selenium only

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

d = webdriver.Chrome(r'path\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://twitter.com/explorer?lang=en')
hashtag_trends = [i.text for i in 
    WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".trend-name")))
    if i.text.startswith('#')
]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For locator trending topic you can using `xpath`.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//*[contains(@class,"trend-name")])[1]').text
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//*[contains(@class,"trend-name")])[1]').click()
```

You can get count the element by :

```
len_locator = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@class,"trend-name")]')
print len(len_locator)
```

Or if you only want locator only start with `#`, you can use :

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//*[@dir="ltr" and starts-with(text(), "#")])[1]').text
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//*[@dir="ltr" and starts-with(text(), "#")])[1]').click
```

You can get count the element by :

```
len_locator = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@dir="ltr" and starts-with(text(), "#")]')
print len(len_locator)
```

It's the first locator of the trending topic, if you want the second and so on, then replace `[1]` to `[2]` etc. Use iteration to the grab all.